# How to create a modern subsite in a classic team sitecollection?

Tags: modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site, modern-document-library, classic-experience

We are using SharePoint Online in O365. We have a classic teamsite as intranet which is also our root SharePoint site from our tenant (http://myCompany.sharepoint.com). I would like to create a subsite but would like to make it modern. For example modern sitepages, document libraries and lists. How can I do this?

Ps. the classic team sitecollection needs to stay classic.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can technically do it (create classic subsite and switch to modern experience) this is not recommended. Modern experience is designed with flat structure in mind and some feature (current and future) may work unpredictably. Modern should be only site collections

> Classic SharePoint architecture is typically built using a
>   hierarchical system of site collections and sub-sites, with inherited
>   navigation, permissions, and site designs. Once built, this structure
>   can be inflexible and difficult to maintain. In the modern SharePoint
>   experience, every site is a site collection and all can be associated
>   with a hub site which is a flat structure of sites that share
>   navigation, branding, and other elements

REF: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/guide-to-sharepoint-modern-experience

The guide about modernization of classic site can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-classic-sites

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modern team subsite which will have modern lists,libraries and pages inside a classic site collection.

The template you can use for that is `STS#3` which can be created as below using PnP PowerShell:

```
$creds = Get-Credential

# Connect to the site collection
Connect-PnPOnline -url  https://tenant.sharepoint.com/ -Credentials $creds

# Create modern sub site
New-PnPWeb -Title "Modern Sub Site" -Url ModernSubSite -Description "Desc" -Template "STS#3" -Locale 1033
```

If you want to create a modern sub-site from UI, you can do as below by going to `Site Contents > Subsite` - (`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx`):

[image]